# how to keep second pdf page hidden until button is selected on first page

Tags: pdf

I've created a pdf user form with the option to only put 10 line items, however, if the user requires to insert additional item codes, I've created a second form for just that. I would like to know if it is possible to keep the second document hidden until the user clicks a button to activate the second sheet - making it accessible to insert addition item codes if needed. Thank you for your help in this matter.

[image]

Comment: Do you expect everyone filling your form to be using Adobe Acrobat or Reader? If "yes", you can create a page template from the second page, hide it, and then spawn a copy of it when the button is pressed. If your answer is "yes", I'll document the process as an answer. If "no", then there is no reliable solution.

Comment: Is the extra sheet on an extra page? Then consider using page templates. Build the pdf with an invisible extra page template and instatiate it on button press.

Comment: joelgeraci - "yes", everyone will be using Adobe Acrobat or Reader. If the user requires additional lines then the second document can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your intent completely from your question.  If you you wish to display your PDF forms as separate pages, it's as simple as this HTML:

```
<button onclick="location.href='SecondPage.html';">Show More</button>
```

Where "SecondPage.html" becomes instead the URL of your second PDF.

*If you wish instead to display the two PDFs on the same web page simultaneously, we'd probably need to see some markup of what you've tried so far*.  You generally get better answers on StackOverflow if you can present examples of what you've tried so far.

But your general approach would probably be a simple one:  Put both PDFs into DIVS with styles applied so that the first DIV is visible and the second DIV is hidden.  Then, the onclick for the button I've written above, instead of displaying a page, would simply call a javascript function that alters the style for the second DIV, changing its style from "hidden" to "block".